# How do I debounce multiple external interrupt buttons?

Tags: interrupt

I have an Arduino sleeping most of the time to save power and there are two buttons attached to different interrupt pins that run different functions.  These functions are different from each other, but both have to run long blocking code.  I don't want the button bouncing (or even deliberately being pressed multiple times during the blocking code) to [queue](http://www.gammon.com.au/interrupts) up multiple runnings of the interrupt function.  I also don't want the sleep period to be short because I'm trying to keep if off as much as possible to save power.  I don't want to have to wait 8 seconds after a button press before the button's action happens.  As such, I would think flags or polling the pins from the main loop are not the way to handle this because of power inefficiency and long latency between button press and action.  Should I have each ISR detached its own interrupt pin until its action is complete and then reattach?

```
const int buttonA = 6;     
const int buttonB =  10;      

void setup() {
  pinMode(buttonA, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(buttonA, INPUT_PULLUP);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(buttonA), actionA, FALLING);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(buttonB), actionB, FALLING);
}

void loop() {
  sleep_function();  //takes 8 seconds
}

void actionA(){
  //some blocking code that takes 2 seconds, but that I want to run immediately upon button press
}

void actionB(){
  //some blocking code that takes 10 seconds, but that I want to run immediately upon button press
}
```

Comment: the blocking code is like having one driver with one vehicle, and without a cell phone, picking up packages

Comment: When using interrupt, I personally prefer to use hardware debouncing with a RC circuit and a Schmitt Trigger. See "RC Debouncer" section of Jack Ganssle's [A Guide to Debouncing](http://www.ganssle.com/debouncing-pt2.htm).

Comment: do not do action on button press ... insert a layer of separation between a button press and the desired action ... a button press should set a flag, nothing more ... the desired action should only occur when flag is set ... that way, multiple button presses are ignored if the flag is already set

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set a flag in the interrupt, and run your code in the loop

```
const int buttonA = 6;     
const int buttonB =  10;
volatile byte flagA = 0;
volatile byte flagB = 0;      

void setup() {
  pinMode(buttonA, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(buttonA, INPUT_PULLUP);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(buttonA), actionA, FALLING);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(buttonB), actionB, FALLING);
}

void loop() {
  if(flagA){
    //some blocking code that takes 2 seconds, but that I want to run immediately upon button press
    flagA = 0;
  }
  if(flagB){
    //some blocking code that takes 10 seconds, but that I want to run immediately upon button press
    flagB = 0;
  }
  sleep_function();  //takes 8 seconds
}

void actionA(){
   flagA = 1;
}

void actionB(){
   flagB = 1;
}
```

Comment: will the interrupt always end the sleep or will it just resume the sleep?

Comment: The interrupt ends the sleep, and if you want to sleep, you have to put it to sleep again.  https://www.gammon.com.au/power